# How to manage update process of an android app with new permission

Tags: android, updates

We have an android game that does not require any special permissions. Our current version is 1.1 and we are planning to release a version 2.0 which requires internet connection. We know that when we release v2.0, our app won't be auto-updated because of the new permission, and will require a manual update.

So we made a plan like this. We will prepare two new apks for the app. First one will be v1.2 and won't contain new permission in the manifest file. Second will be v2.0 and will contain new permission. We will upload these two apks with a few minutes interval. We expect that people having auto update enabled will get v1.2 automatically. When they open their v1.2 app, we will open a dialog telling them to manually update their app and when they click on OK button in the dialog we will open Play Store. So they will be forced to update their app to v2.0 manually.

We want to know if this approach is ok and how other people manage update process with this "new permission" situation.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a new `.akp` in the Google Play Store takes some hours on the servers before they are live for upgrade. So it is not guaranteed that your first uploaded app will be published before your second if you are uploading in such a small intervall (better upload with a 2-4 hours shift).

Also I would upload the Version 2.0 before the 1.2 so you can be sure the newer version is available when the Dialog prompts to update your app. People get confused if they get told to manually upgrade an ther is no update in the store. You can still indicate by the version-code which `.apk` is newer with a higher number. The order of the upload should not count for indicating the newest version.

Just for the info, I was never in this situation.